# MS Project 2016 real time collaboration (co-authoring)

Tags: collaboration

MS Office 2016 has a great real time collaboration tool. Does anyone know is it working for MS Project 2016? If not what is the best way to work on the same MS Project file?

Moreover when we open the same file from one drive all the changes in the file are being saved in the new files now.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/has-anyone-used-co-authoring-with-project-2016/98c432e2-6de5-4493-8663-ca0a0b356104) thread:

> Co-authoring is not available in any version of Microsoft Project,
>   including the 2016 version.  Only one user can have a project open for
>   editing at a time.  Hope this helps.

an [older post](http://www.msofficeforums.com/project/26615-project-2013-standard-how-achieve-multi-user.html) says:

> I'm sorry, no. Even if the file is stored in SharePoint, Project does
>   not allow co-authoring. Not even with Project Server can multiple
>   people edit the same project file at the same time.

On yet [another thread](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1636513),

> You can distribute extracts using Excel and get replies which the PM
>   evaluates and incorporates into the schedule as appropriate.

I found this while searching for answers myself.
If evidence is found against this, I can update the answer, but it doesn't look like there are any updates in the foreseeable future.